# Validate Secure Window Public API unclear example on docs

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I was reading the docs on [Validate Secure Window Public API (secure-window)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/cli_rules_secure_window.htm) for LockerService and I'm not able to understand the example given:

> The following patterns are considered problematic:

```
onclick: function (cmp, evt, help) {
    window.open('bar');
}
```

> The following patterns use features of the Lightning Components framework and are suggested as an alternative:

```
onclick: function (cmp, evt, help) {
    setTimeout(function () {}, 100);
}
```

I'm supposed to be using window.open inside the setTimeout function or should I implement a similar function to window.open inside the setTimeout? Either way It's not clear enough for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just means that `setTimeout` is considered a safe function and is allowed whereas `open` is not. You can invoke `setTimeout` with LockerService enabled and not have problems, but if you invoke `open` you'll get an error due to LockerService.

Directly above the examples on the doc page, [Validate Secure Window Public API (secure-window)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/cli_rules_secure_window.htm), the following lists the window methods that are allowed:

> Supported window functions and properties include the following:
>
> - addEventListener
> - setInterval
> - setTimeout
> - $A
> - document
> - location
> - navigator
> - window

Note that `setTimeout` is listed, whereas `open` is not.